# XAMPP and GitHub Questions

Tags: mysql, database, github, xampp

So im a newcomer to github, and i have some question regarding with databases, especially im using xampp since we still in that step at our university.

Can i and my friend work on the same databases but we connect the database with github, or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: *"we connect the database with github"* - unfortunately no, not realtime. you can export the `.sql` file to allow your friend to have the DDL (and possibly DML), but this approach is not exactly stellar. it would be better if you work with modern [tag:ORM] frameworks that allows database migrations. if you want something realtime, you can try something like [tag:supabase].